# Is it possible to make a flash based game without graphic skills? Is actionscript all I need?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

If I have a designer make the necessary graphics, what do I need to learn to make a flash based game?

Is it action script only?

I already understand the backend server work that would need to talk to the 'front end' part of the game i.e. how the flash game will make requests to the backend servers for storing/retrieving data in xml/json etc.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you only need ActionScript. All game logic and what is neccessary for rendering can be done directly in code.

There are some very good game libraries out there, flixel and flashpunk come to mind. There is even a physics library, box2dflash.

Here is all you need to get started: [gamepoetry.com](http://www.gamepoetry.com/blog/2008/03/26/make-flash-games-for-free/)

I could also provide you with some very good tutorials on the subject, if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create an Actionscript only game.  If you learn the Actionscript drawing API, you can even programatically draw graphics and may not need a designer (depends on the complexity you want).

Even if you want to use imported graphics, you can do it without paying for the full version of Flash by using the Flex compiler.  You can use it to create Actionscript only files without the Flex framework, or with it if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've written games/activities, albeit standalone, entirely in ActionScript without any graphics. So, Yes :)